# How to get rid of freezing screen when fetching too much data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 1700 posts in the firebase database but when I connect using firebase the screen is frozen for 30 seconds to a minute and the data is fetched

Note : The screen is not frozen if the posts are few

**Code**

```
void start() {
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = database.getReference("YO").child("Posts");
        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Posts.add(new PostsModel(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.child("AuthorName").getValue().toString(), dataSnapshot.child("Title").getValue().toString()));
                saveSystem.SaveArrayList("PostsList", Posts);
                saveSystem.SaveBooleanData("FirstTime", false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: why don't you try to use pagination , it will make it more easy for you to load data without any UI problem

Comment: @B.mansouri I dont use recyclerview or listview just textview when press next then get next post

Comment: aha , so try to use async function do the fetch in background and change the textView value after in the UI thread

Comment: you can put example

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 4):

Although listening to event changes with for example `addChildEventListener()` is on the background thread, anything that happens inside the `onChildAdded()` is on the main UI thread when the process is started on the that thread. In order to improve performance for large data move the parsing or file operation to a background thread.

To perform the heavy lifting you can use a `AsyncTask`(which is good for beginners and novices). I usually find it easier to just spin off my own new Thread to hand this kind of thing.

Comment: is there a solution?

Comment: Thats the solution, also, 30 seconds to 1 minute to just fetch 1700 results its too much, check of loading in chunks of 100 , it will be faster

Comment: I like your answer and ideas, maybe provide an example and/or link to the documentation

Answer (score 1):

You wanna do tasks with heavy workload in the background either using `AsyncTask` or a `Runnable`

Example:

`new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your work here
        }
    }).start();`

Comment: put all codes in start funcation inside run funcation?

Comment: The part of your code that takes the longest to execute. So probably everything after "database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();"

Comment: I put from here databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){...}); but still not working

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work" can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

in Java:

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
 }
```

in java it's like that .

and you can check this official documentation :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask